# Index Beyond Bounds / EXC_BAD_ACCESS upon Core Data Delete SwiftUI

Tags: core-data, swiftui, exc-bad-instruction

I'm getting a `Index Beyond Bounds` error and a `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)` when trying to delete a Core Data index in SwiftUI.

Basically, I have a Core Data entity (`Dates`), containing only a `date` attribute (Constraint - String). This has a one-to-many relationship with my `Records` Entity. I am trying to display a list of all `date`'s I have. Displaying is fine, but upon trying to delete it, my app crashes.

My View currently looks as following:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Settings: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @FetchRequest(entity: Dates.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var dates: FetchedResults<Dates>


    var body: some View {
            VStack {
                List{
                ForEach(dates, id: \.self) { day in
                    Text("\(day.wrappedDate)")
                }.onDelete { (indexSet) in
                let dateToDelete = self.dates[indexSet.first!]
                self.managedObjectContext.delete(dateToDelete)
                do {
                    try self.managedObjectContext.save()
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
                }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

I've broken my view down to the bare minimum to see if that would help, but unfortunately not.

When trying to delete. The error I get in the output is:

```
2020-04-29 16:08:23.980755+0300 TESTTEST[28270:2245700] [General] *** -[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty NSArray
```

If I have say 9 dates, it would say `index 8 beyond bounds [0 .. 7]`, so it's not necessarily related to an empty Array.

Further output is:

```
=== AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute X ===
```

a bunch of times, followed by:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)
```

on my AppDelegate.

Could the issue be in generating the view - rather than the delete?

Please be aware that I'm a self-taught, absolute Noob when it comes to coding, so I might be missing something obvious here. Any help on getting to the answer myself in the form of instructions would also be greatly appreciated (so I can learn how to fix this).

**EDIT:**

I think I found out what's causing the issue. In another view I'm also generating a list of all `date`s , where I apply an index on `Dates`. Will amend code now to see if this fixes it....

TBC!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a separate view I was calling a list of dates in the following way:

```
ForEach(0 ..< self.dates.count, id: \.self) { index in
       Text("\(self.dates[index].date)")
}
```

Deleting one of the Date entities, would mess up the indices presented in this view. Changing this structure to the below fixed the issue:

```
ForEach(self.dates, id: \.self) { day in
Text("\(day.date)")
}
```